# Best way to distribute a given resource (eg. budget) for optimal output

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to find a solution in which a given resource (eg. budget) will be best distributed to different options which yields different results on the resource provided.

Let's say I have `N = 1200` and some functions. (a, b, c, d are some unknown variables)

```
f1(x) = a * x
f2(x) = b * x^c
f3(x) = a*x + b*x^2 + c*x^3
f4(x) = d^x
f5(x) = log x^d
...
```

And also, let's say there `n` number of these functions that yield different results based on its input `x`, where `x = 0 or x >= m`, where `m` is a constant.

Although I am not able to find exact formula for the given functions, I am able to find the output. This means that I can do:

`X = f1(N1) + f2(N2) + f3(N3) + ... + fn(Nn)` where `(N1 + ... Nn) = N` as many times as there are ways of distributing `N` into `n` numbers, and find a specific case where `X` is the greatest.

How would I actually go about finding the best distribution of `N` with the least computation power, using whatever libraries currently available?

Comment: What upper bounds on the ranges of values of `N` and `n` are you expecting?

Comment: @EvilTak I am expecting `N` to be upwardly boundless, as I cannot safely assume how much resource may be allowed, but the minimum for `N` will be 1100. As for `n`, it will be no more than 65K. I also forgot to mention that there is rule for each distribution. I added this rule to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy with allocations constrained to be whole numbers then there is a dynamic programming solution of cost O(Nn) - so you can increase accuracy by scaling if you want, but this will increase cpu time.

For each i=1 to n maintain an array where element j gives the maximum yield using only the first i functions giving them a total allowance of j.

For i=1 this is simply the result of f1().

For i=k+1 consider when working out the result for j consider each possible way of splitting j units between f_{k+1}() and the table that tells you the best return from a distribution among the first k functions - so you can calculate the table for i=k+1 using the table created for k.

At the end you get the best possible return for n functions and N resources. It makes it easier to find out what that best answer is if you maintain of a set of arrays telling the best way to distribute k units among the first i functions, for all possible values of i and k. Then you can look up the best allocation for f100(), subtract off the value this allocated to f100() from N, look up the best allocation for f99() given the resulting resources, and carry on like this until you have worked out the best allocations for all f().

As an example suppose f1(x) = 2x, f2(x) = x^2 and f3(x) = 3 if x>0 and 0 otherwise. Suppose we have 3 units of resource.

The first table is just f1(x) which is 0, 2, 4, 6 for 0,1,2,3 units.

The second table is the best you can do using f1(x) and f2(x) for 0,1,2,3 units and is 0, 2, 4, 9, switching from f1 to f2 at x=2.

The third table is 0, 3, 5, 9. I can get 3 and 5 by using 1 unit for f3() and the rest for the best solution in the second table. 9 is simply the best solution in the second table - there is no better solution using 3 resources that gives any of them to f(3)

So 9 is the best answer here. One way to work out how to get there is to keep the tables around and recalculate that answer. 9 comes from f3(0) + 9 from the second table so all 3 units are available to f2() + f1(). The second table 9 comes from f2(3) so there are no units left for f(1) and we get f1(0) + f2(3) + f3(0).

When you are working the resources to use at stage i=k+1 you have a table form i=k that tells you exactly the result to expect from the resources you have left over after you have decided to use some at stage i=k+1. The best distribution does not become incorrect because that stage i=k you have worked out the result for the best distribution given every possible number of remaining resources.

Comment: How should the table for i=k look like? Can you provide a small example?

Comment: If I am finding best distribution between (i = k) vs (i = K+1), how can I know that the best distribution for (i = k) has not become incorrect as I decrease the resource that was used to calculate its distribution?

Comment: (I have added an example and tried to answer this question in my answer)

Comment: Great example. Marked as answer! :D